# How to reverse a HVect in Idris?

Tags: idris

I'm new to Irdis. Is it possible to reverse a [`HVect`](http://www.idris-lang.org/docs/0.10/base_doc/docs/Data.HVect.html)? If I call reverse on a `HVect [String, Int]` it should return a `HVect [Int, String]` and if I call reverse on a `HVect [String, Int, Day]` it should return a `HVect [Day, Int, String]`.

I tried to reuse `Data.Vect.reverse` ([Gist](https://gist.github.com/maiermic/9440758a27312ba09988ffca90a48bee))

```
module reverse_hvect

import Data.HVect

reverse : HVect ts -> HVect (reverse ts)
reverse [] = []
reverse (x::xs) = (reverse xs) ++ [x]
```

but I get

```
Type checking .\reverse_hvect.idr
reverse_hvect.idr:7:9:When checking right hand side of reverse_hvect.reverse with expected type
        HVect (reverse (t :: ts))

Type mismatch between
        HVect (Data.Vect.reverse, go Type k ts [] ts ++ [t]) (Type of reverse xs ++ [x])
and
        HVect (Data.Vect.reverse, go Type (S k) (t :: ts) [t] ts) (Expected type)

Specifically:
        Type mismatch between
                Data.Vect.reverse, go Type k ts [] ts ++ [t]
        and
                Data.Vect.reverse, go Type (S k) (t :: ts) [t] ts
Holes: reverse_hvect.reverse
```

Since `Data.Vect.reverse` uses an inner function `go` with an accumulator, I wrote my own `Vect.reverse` with the same structure as my `HVect.reverse` ([Gist](https://gist.github.com/maiermic/c669bcf7cfe9a9e10450e47f0d6802f4))

```
module reverse_hvect

import Data.Vect
import Data.HVect

myReverse : Vect n a -> Vect n a
myReverse [] = []
myReverse {n = S k} (x::xs) = rewrite plusCommutative 1 k in (myReverse xs) ++ [x]

reverse : HVect ts -> HVect (myReverse ts)
reverse [] = []
reverse (x::xs) = (reverse xs) ++ [x]
```

but I get another error

```
Type checking .\reverse_hvect.idr
reverse_hvect.idr:12:9:When checking right hand side of reverse_hvect.reverse with expected type
        HVect (myReverse (t :: ts))

Type mismatch between
        HVect (myReverse ts ++ [t]) (Type of reverse xs ++ [x])
and
        HVect (replace (sym (replace (sym (replace (sym (plusZeroRightNeutral k)) Refl)) (replace (sym (plusSuccRightSucc k 0)) Refl))) (myReverse ts ++ [t])) (Expected type)

Specifically:
        Type mismatch between
                myReverse ts ++ [t]
        and
                replace (sym (replace (sym (replace (sym (plusZeroRightNeutral k)) Refl)) (replace (sym (plusSuccRightSucc k 0)) Refl))) (myReverse ts ++ [t])
Holes: reverse_hvect.reverse
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

user3237465's answer in Idris:

```
import Data.Vect
import Data.HVect

nreverse : Nat -> Nat
nreverse Z = Z
nreverse (S n) = nreverse n + 1

vreverse : Vect n a -> Vect (nreverse n) a
vreverse [] = []
vreverse (x :: xs) = vreverse xs ++ [x]

hreverse : HVect ts -> HVect (vreverse ts)
hreverse [] = []
hreverse (x :: xs) = hreverse xs ++ [x]
```

You had the right idea with the same structures in the different reverses, but tried the more difficult structure.

Answer (score 2):

Having `rewrite`s at the type level is a bad idea. I don't have the Idris type checker, but it should be straightforward to adapt this Agda code:

```
open import Data.Nat.Base
open import Data.Vec hiding (reverse)

infixr 5 _∷ₕ_ _++ₕ_

nreverse : ℕ -> ℕ
nreverse  0      = 0
nreverse (suc n) = nreverse n + 1

vreverse : ∀ {n α} {A : Set α} -> Vec A n -> Vec A (nreverse n)
vreverse  []      = []
vreverse (x ∷ xs) = vreverse xs ++ (x ∷ [])

data HList : ∀ {n} -> Vec Set n -> Set where
  []ₕ  : HList []
  _∷ₕ_ : ∀ {n A} {As : Vec Set n} -> A -> HList As -> HList (A ∷ As)

_++ₕ_ : ∀ {n m} {As : Vec Set n} {Bs : Vec Set m} -> HList As -> HList Bs -> HList (As ++ Bs)
[]ₕ       ++ₕ ys = ys
(x ∷ₕ xs) ++ₕ ys = x ∷ₕ xs ++ₕ ys

reverseₕ : ∀ {n} {As : Vec Set n} -> HList As -> HList (vreverse As)
reverseₕ  []ₕ      = []ₕ
reverseₕ (x ∷ₕ xs) = reverseₕ xs ++ₕ (x ∷ₕ []ₕ)
```

I.e. you just need one another `reverse` in the tower of reverses, namely the one that "reverses" a number.

BTW, [`reverse`](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/base/Data/Vect.idr#L141) for `Vect`s in the Idris library is more involved than it should be. [Here](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/blob/master/src/Data/Vec.agda#L150) is a rewrite-free version.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Agda. I really would appreciate a translation to Idris.

Comment: What do you mean by "broken"? It doesn't use foldl, but that's because the foldl in the Foldable interface doesn't capture the change in size. It's essentially the same algorithm.

Comment: @Edwin Brady, perhaps "broken" is not a right word. I mean that these `plusZeroRightNeutral` and `plusSuccRightSucc` are not necessary, when `reverse` is defined via `foldl`.