# How to determine all sub-dimensions of a HVect?

Tags: dependent-type, idris

I'd like to determine all sub-dimensions of a `HVect` as a `HVect`.

**Example:**

```
import Data.HVect

myHVect : HVect [Int, String, List Nat]
myHVect = [42, "text", [1, 2, 3]]

subDimensions : HVect [ HVect [Int], HVect [Int, String], HVect [Int, String, List Nat] ]
subDimensions = subDimHVect myHVect
-- [ [42], [42, "text"], [42, "text", [1, 2, 3]] ]
```

My approach looks like this:

```
subDimHVect v = subDimHVect' [] [] v
  where
    subDimHVect' result _ [] = result
    subDimHVect' result lastDim (x::xs) =
      let nextDim = lastDim ++ [x] in
      subDimHVect' (result ++ [nextDim]) nextDim xs
```

but I don't know how to type `subDimHVect` and `subDimHVect'` correctly. Implementation seems to be fine:

**Manual Calculation of the example:**

```
subDimHVect [42, "text", [1, 2, 3]]
  = subDimHVect' [] [] [42, "text", [1, 2, 3]]
  = subDimHVect' [[42]] [42] ["text", [1, 2, 3]]
  = subDimHVect' [[42], [42, "text"]] [42, "text"] [[1, 2, 3]]
  = subDimHVect' [[42], [42, "text"], [42, "text", [1, 2, 3]]] [42, "text", [1, 2, 3]] []
  = [[42], [42, "text"], [42, "text", [1, 2, 3]]]
```

I'm quite new to Idris and dependent types. I would appreciate some help to find the missing type signatures.

**Edit:**
I found another approach that might be easier to type, even though I couldn't figure the type out either ([definition of `reverse`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36443627/1065654)):

```
subDimHVect v = reverse (subDimHVect' (reverse v))
  where
    subDimHVect' [] = []
    subDimHVect' (x::xs) = [(x::xs)] ++ (subDimHVect' xs)
```

**Manual Calculation of the example (using the second approach):**

```
subDimHVect [42, "text", [1, 2, 3]]
  = reverse (subDimHVect' (reverse [42, "text", [1, 2, 3]]))
  = reverse (subDimHVect' [[1, 2, 3], "text", 42])
  = reverse ([ [[1, 2, 3], "text", 42] ] ++ (subDimHVect' ["text", 42]))
  = reverse ([ [[1, 2, 3], "text", 42] ] ++ [ ["text", 42] ] ++ (subDimHVect' [42]))
  = reverse ([ [[1, 2, 3], "text", 42] ] ++ [ ["text", 42] ] ++ [ [42] ] ++ (subDimHVect' []))
  = reverse ([ [[1, 2, 3], "text", 42] ] ++ [ ["text", 42] ] ++ [ [42] ] ++ [])
  = reverse ([ [[1, 2, 3], "text", 42], ["text", 42], [42] ])
  = [ [42], [42, "text"], [42, "text", [1, 2, 3]] ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First attempt:

```
subDimensions : HVect ts -> HVect xs
```

The `xs` would be treated as an implicit argument (as in `subDimensions : {ts : Vect n Type} -> {xs : Vect k Type} -> HVect ts -> HVect xs`), so the caller could say how the resulting `HVect` will look like. That's not right. We could create the `xs` alongside (see this answer's history if you find out how):

```
subDimensions : HVect {k} ts -> (xs : (Vect k Type) ** HVect xs)
```

However, a

```
subDimensions : HVect ts -> HVect (dimType ts)
```

would be more useful. Following your second attempt, we can create

```
dimType : Vect k Type -> Vect k Type
dimType [] = []
dimType (x :: xs) = (HVect (vreverse (x::xs))) :: dimType xs
```

and following the structure of the type, we define the helper `subDimensions'`:

```
subDimensions' : HVect ts -> HVect (dimType ts)
subDimensions' [] = []
subDimensions' (x :: xs) = (hreverse (x :: xs)) :: subDimensions' xs
```

and the wrapper

```
subDimensions : HVect ts -> HVect (vreverse (dimType (vreverse ts)))
subDimensions xs = hreverse $ subDimensions' $ hreverse xs
```

(for the definition of `hreverse` and `vreverse` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36430390/how-to-reverse-a-hvect-in-idris/36443627#36443627))

Comment: Thanks, but I get `No such variable dim` in `subDimensions`.

Comment: @MegaMuetzenMike Sorry, mixed that line up. It should be correct now!